# Plane coloring $\mathbb{R}^2$, $2$ colors per line

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a coloring of $3$ colors on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that every line contains exactly $2$ (different) colors and there is no triangle with unit area whose vertices lie on $3$ different colors? All points have to be colored. All $3$ colors have to be used.

Comment: Look up [Monsky's theorem](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/Monsky70.pdf). This question appears to be intimately related to its proof..